# How to fix Error CSS asset compiling on Heroku?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

### The issue

I'm building a website to display my CV. Everything works locally but now the code deployed on Heroku has some errors. When I open the app I get a white window with the errors below.

```
Error compiling CSS asset
NoMethodError: undefined method [] for nil:NilClass
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-2.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_processor.rb:278:in 'sprockets_context'
```

### What I've done

I thought it could be related to the asset pipeline compilation.
I have played with the precompile methods in the config/application.rb:

```
 config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
 config.assets.precompile += %w[pe-icon-7-stroke.css Linearicons-Free.scss]
 config.assets.precompile += %w[fonts/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css]
```

I also tried the `config.assets.compile=true` in production.rb which didn't work and is unrecommended anyway.
Also tried `config.assets.digest = true` which didn't work either

I got a few entries in the heroku logs but no error:

```
2019-07-02T11:45:07.360944+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/
application-8936ba387834b0168927f3ea249b81440a8b50afd9f157fb012a0efafef6ba94.css"
host=eugenieordonneau.herokuapp.com request_id=3732ee23-c021-4a48-91e8-a38b075fb231 
fwd="151.229.83.124" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1235ms status=304 bytes=217 protocol=https
```

Let me know if you need more information!
thank you

Comment: Hi Eugenie, when i encounter issues with prod on heroku, i usually run it locally in production mode and that usually helps identify the problem, you can browse logs and look at server console as it happens.

Also check are you using bootstrap sass? if so check the version since i saw this similar problem reported here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/366

Comment: Hi Brad, Sorry for the delay. Thank you for your help. I tried your suggestions but it didn't work. I then realised  that commenting out stuff like `config.assets.compile=true` didn't change it back to false. So I started from scratched again and added each asset one per one. And it worked so I might have played a bit too much with the config parameters.

Comment: Glad you got it working :)